# LocalValidatorFactoryBean not autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring-webmvc 5, and have created validator `MyValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator` with `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` factory field.
I want to use in my app both Bean Validation and Spring Validation
but I get error when use `@Autowired` on factory field: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean' available`

Hibernate Validator is in classpath
Validator and config:

```
@Service
public class MyValidator implements 
org.springframework.validation.Validator {
   @Autowired
   private LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory;
   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
       ...some code...
   }
   @Override
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors){
       javax.validation.Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
       ...some code...
   }
} 
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"controller","service"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
   ...some code...
   @Bean
   public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
   }
}
```

Comment: if bean is private it cannot be accessed from outside class!

Comment: I am afraid that You have to post more of Your code(Try to create a minimal set of code that allows reproducing issue).

Comment: @Sanjari, but as I know Spring uses reflection to access private fields

Comment: @snieguu, I published last version of my code, so now I get error:No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean' available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think probably you use wrong `@ComponentScan`

According to the spring documentation value `field` of `ComponentScan`

> Allows for more concise annotation declarations if no other attributes are needed — for example, @ComponentScan("org.my.pkg") instead of @ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.my.pkg").

I doubt that your packages are named "controller" or service"
So simply remove it or replace it with the correct name of the root package that You want to scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Problem was that not only web config included @ComponentScan({"service","controller"}), root config included @ComponentScan("service") too